# Is there way to removing spacing in the end of data of columns in the mysql

Tags: mysql

I have problem to my data that I load to the database via csv file. the column in the csv has no spacing however after I load the data. some of columns has spacing.

**This is the script that I used to load the data to my table.**

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/Buks/Desktop/dates.csv' INTO TABLE cron_db.dates_reference
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '`' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
(@var1,fiscal_year,fiscal_month,period,week,week2,yearbefore,periodbefore,weekbefore,week2before,ypw)
SET date_record = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%c/%e/%Y');
```

**My CSV:**

[image: My File]

**Data Loaded in the table:**

[image: Loaded Data]

Comment: Maybe see TRIM()

Comment: Thanks Strawberry. let me try on that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have defined your column as `CHAR(n)` - with a fixed length and this forces MySQL to pad with spaces on the right. If this is not your case then you can try with [`TRIM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/Buks/Desktop/dates.csv' INTO TABLE cron_db.dates_reference
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '`' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
(@var1,fiscal_year,fiscal_month,period,week,week2,yearbefore,periodbefore,weekbefore,week2before,@va2)
SET date_record = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%c/%e/%Y'), ypw = TRIM(@var2);
```

Comment: I suspect the source data contains erroneous spaces